# Solana Metaplex V1 accept SPL token for auction

Tags: typescript, solana, metaplex

I'm using the Metaplex Storefront V1 for my auctions and I would like to implement SPL tokens for auctions as far as I know the earlier version of the storefront was able to accept SPL tokens basically with a dropdown menu, but the latest version does not contain this feature. I've only found a harcoded way to accept SPL token for temporary.

```
export const WRAPPED_SOL_MINT = new PublicKey('So11111111111111111111111111111111111111112',);
```

I would like to create my own SPL token with "spl-token create-token" commandlet and accept it in my store.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've dived into the code and I've found this feature. It was hidden thanks to a condition. Exact code where it can be found:

```
{
  hasOtherTokens && (
    <label className="action-field">
      <span className="field-title">Auction mint</span>
      <span className="field-info">
        This will be the quote mint for your auction.
      </span>
      <TokenButton mint={mint} onClick={() => setShowTokenDialog(true)} />
      <TokenDialog
        setMint={setMint}
        open={showTokenDialog}
        onClose={() => {
          setShowTokenDialog(false);
        }}
      />
    </label>
  );
}
```

[image: asd]

[image]

With this feature, I was able to set up an auction that accept unique SPL token as currency.